# Is it possible to constrain an (abstract) base method only on the return type but keep the parameters flexible?

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy

Is it possible to constrain an (abstract) base method only on the return type but keep the arguments of that method entirely flexible for children to implement in any way they want?

E.g.

```
import abc

class Mother(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> int:
        pass


class Child(Mother):

    def foo(self, val: int) -> int:
        return val * 2
```

This raises:

```
$ mypy inheritance.py 
inheritance.py:12: error: Signature of "foo" incompatible with supertype "Mother"
```

Because `Child` implements `foo` with an argument `val` that isn't defined in the `foo` method of `Mother`.

The only way I see is to make `Mother` generic over some container type that `foo` would accept but what I really want is to be as flexible in `Child` as I want so that I can use any number of parameters and really be only constraint in the return type of the method.

Comment: Regardless of whether you can get it past the type checker, this is in violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If you do this, you cannot substitute any `Mother` by a `Child` and expect it to work, because any call to `foo` will fail. It might be better design to give `Child.foo` a different name instead.

Comment: I actually agree but I have some constraints to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with:

```
import abc

class Mother(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        pass


class Child(Mother):

    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return args[0] * 2
```

You might want some additional checking inside `Child.foo`.

Comment: It's what I thought. I just thought there might be some other solution that I'm missing.